# logic behind below javascript code required

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm going through some javascript and jQuery examples and some where i came  across below code but i couldn't  understand totally. I want to know what is the condition it is trying to validate.

```
function checkPostCode(toCheck)
{
  var alpha1 = "[abcdefghijklmnoprstuwyz]";                       // Character 1
  var alpha2 = "[abcdefghklmnopqrstuvwxy]";                       // Character 2
  var alpha3 = "[abcdefghjkpmnrstuvwxy]";                         // Character 3
  var alpha4 = "[abehmnprvwxy]";                                  // Character 4
  var alpha5 = "[abdefghjlnpqrstuwxyz]";                          // Character 5
  var pcexp = new Array ();
  pcexp.push (new RegExp ("^(" + alpha1 + "{1}" + alpha2 + "?[0-9]{1,2})(\\s*)([0-9]{1}" + alpha5 + "{2})$","i"));
  pcexp.push (new RegExp ("^(" + alpha1 + "{1}[0-9]{1}" + alpha3 + "{1})(\\s*)([0-9]{1}" + alpha5 + "{2})$","i"));
  pcexp.push (new RegExp ("^(" + alpha1 + "{1}" + alpha2 + "{1}" + "?[0-9]{1}" + alpha4 +"{1})(\\s*)([0-9]{1}" + alpha5 + "{2})$","i"));
  pcexp.push (/^(GIR)(\s*)(0AA)$/i);
  pcexp.push (/^(bfpo)(\s*)([0-9]{1,4})$/i);
  pcexp.push (/^(bfpo)(\s*)(c\/o\s*[0-9]{1,3})$/i);
  pcexp.push (/^([A-Z]{4})(\s*)(1ZZ)$/i);
  var postCode = toCheck;
  var valid = false;
  for ( var i=0; i<pcexp.length; i++) {
    if (pcexp[i].test(postCode)) {
      pcexp[i].exec(postCode);
      postCode = RegExp.$1.toUpperCase() + " " + RegExp.$3.toUpperCase();
      postCode = postCode.replace (/C\/O\s*/,"c/o ");
      valid = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (valid) {return postCode;} else return false;
}
```

Comment: Please provide links to where these examples originated. The context may help us understand the question.

Based on variable names, it looks like it's trying to validate postal codes and is trying to cover a variety of international formats.

Comment: It's UK PostCode Validation from here: http://www.websemantics.co.uk/resources/useful_javascript_functions/ (search for postcode on the page)

Comment: It's same as @mellamokb gave http://www.websemantics.co.uk/resources/useful_javascript_functions

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is referred to as "client side validation".

There are several regular expressions that are being added to the array `pcexp`.  The `for()` loop checks each regular expression in the array, one at a time, to see if `postCode` matches the pattern.

"If `postCode` matches the current regular expression" is what the `if()` statement inside the loop is saying.

The `if()` statement at the end checks whether `postCode` was matched against a pattern in the loop, thereby causing `valid` to be set to true.